# Reading xml and parsing to html

Tags: javascript, xml, html

I am trying to read an xml and print it contents to screen.  The table comes up correctly but I cannot figure out why each data row is not populating properly.

**HTML:**

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cv.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/2.3.2/simplex/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <title>CV</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="menu" class="navbar navbar-fluid-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>
            <button class="btn btn-large" onclick="getEducation()">Education</button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button class="btn btn-large" onclick="getEmployment()">Employment</button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button class="btn btn-large" onclick="getPublications()">Publications</button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button class="btn btn-large" onclick="getProjects()">Projects</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="header" class="row" style="text-align:center;">
      <h1>Curriculum Vitae</h1>
      <br/>
      <h2>Assignment 4-1</h2>
      <br/>
      <h3 class="text-success bold">Bradley Woods</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="container" class="container-fluid"> 

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var xmlDoc
function getEducation() 
{
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML='<h3>Education</h3> <br/>';
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML+='<table class="table table-striped"> <th>Name</th><th>Institution</th> <th>Address</th> <th>Year</th><th>Major</th><th>Minor</th>'
    var xmlObj = xmlDoc.documentElement;
    var edus = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DEGREE");


    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "cv.xml", false);
    var vitae = xmlhttp.responseXML;

    var edu = vitae.getElementsByTagName("DEGREE");
    for (i=0; i < edu.length; i++)
    {
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML+='<tr>';
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML+='<td> <h4>' + edu[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].NodeValue + '/<h4></td>';
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML+='<td> <h4>' + edu[i].getElementsByTagName("INSTITUTION")[0].childNodes[0].NodeValue + '/<h4></td>';
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML+='<td> <h4>' + edu[i].getElementsByTagName("ADDRESS")[0].childNodes[0].NodeValue + '/<h4></td>';
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML+='<td> <h4>' + edu[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].NodeValue + '/<h4></td>';
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML+='<td> <h4>' + edu[i].getElementsByTagName("MAJOR")[0].childNodes[0].NodeValue + '/<h4></td>';
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML+='<td> <h4>' + edu[i].getElementsByTagName("MINOR")[0].childNodes[0].NodeValue + '/<h4></td>';
    }
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML+='</table>'

}





function getEmployment() {
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML="<h3>Employment</h3>";
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML+='<table class="table table-striped"> <th>Name</th><th>Address</th> <th>Title</th> <th>Begin</th><th>End</th><th>Responsibilities</th>'
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML+='</table>'


}

function getPublications() 
{
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML="<h3>Publications</h3>";
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML+='<table class="table table-striped"> <th>Title</th><th>Author(s)</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Year</th><th>Begin Page</th><th>End Page</th><th>Volue</th><th>Volume Number</th>'
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML+='</table>'
}


function getProjects() 
{
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML="<h3>Projects</h3>";
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML+='<table class="table table-striped"> <th>Title</th><th>Name</th> <th>Amount</th> <th>Begin</th><th>End</th><th>Role</th>'
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML+='</table>'
}
```

**XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE VITAE SYSTEM "vitae.dtd">
<VITAE>
    <DEGREE>
        <NAME>Bachelors Computer Science</NAME>
        <INSTITUTION>Franklin University</INSTITUTION>
        <ADDRESS>201 S Grant Ave, Columbus, OH 43215</ADDRESS>
        <YEAR>2013</YEAR>
        <MAJOR>Computer Science</MAJOR>
        <MINOR>Software design</MINOR>
    </DEGREE>
    <DEGREE>
        <NAME>Master's Computer Science</NAME>
        <INSTITUTION>Franklin University</INSTITUTION>
        <ADDRESS>201 S Grant Ave, Columbus, OH 43215</ADDRESS>
        <YEAR>2014</YEAR>
        <MAJOR>Computer Science</MAJOR>
        <MINOR>Aritificial Intelligence</MINOR>
    </DEGREE>
    <DEGREE>
        <NAME>PHD Computer Science</NAME>
        <INSTITUTION>Franklin University</INSTITUTION>
        <ADDRESS>201 S Grant Ave, Columbus, OH 43215</ADDRESS>
        <YEAR>2015</YEAR>
        <MAJOR>Computer Science</MAJOR>
        <MINOR>Game Theory</MINOR>
    </DEGREE>
    <EMPLOYMENT>
        <NAME>IBM</NAME>
        <ADDRESS>8235 Estates Parkway Plain City, OH 43064</ADDRESS>
        <TITLE>Software Developer</TITLE>
        <BEGIN>01/01/2012</BEGIN>
        <END>12/31/2012</END>
        <RESPONSIBILITIES>Unit Testing</RESPONSIBILITIES>
    </EMPLOYMENT>
    <EMPLOYMENT>
        <NAME>Microsoft</NAME>
        <ADDRESS>One Microsoft Way Redmond, WA 98052-6399</ADDRESS>
        <TITLE>Software Developer</TITLE>
        <BEGIN>01/01/2013</BEGIN>
        <END>12/31/2013</END>
        <RESPONSIBILITIES>OS Developer</RESPONSIBILITIES>
    </EMPLOYMENT>
    <EMPLOYMENT>
        <NAME>Twitter</NAME>
        <ADDRESS>1355 Market St, Suite 900 San Francisco, CA 94103</ADDRESS>
        <TITLE>Software Developer</TITLE>
        <BEGIN>01/01/2010</BEGIN>
        <END>12/31/2010</END>
        <RESPONSIBILITIES>Twitter Search Developer</RESPONSIBILITIES>
    </EMPLOYMENT>
    <EMPLOYMENT>
        <NAME>Yahoo Inc</NAME>
        <ADDRESS> 701 1st Ave, Sunnyvale, CA 94089</ADDRESS>
        <TITLE>Software Developer</TITLE>
        <BEGIN>01/01/2011</BEGIN>
        <END>12/13/2011</END>
        <RESPONSIBILITIES>Develop Gaming Apps</RESPONSIBILITIES>
    </EMPLOYMENT>
    <EMPLOYMENT>
        <NAME>ESPN</NAME>
        <ADDRESS> 545 Middle St, Bristol, CT 06010</ADDRESS>
        <TITLE>Software Developer</TITLE>
        <BEGIN>01/01/2010</BEGIN>
        <END>12/13/2010</END>
        <RESPONSIBILITIES>Develop Gaming Apps</RESPONSIBILITIES>
    </EMPLOYMENT>
    <PUBLICATION>
        <AUTHOR>Bradley Woods</AUTHOR>
        <AUTHOR>Bill Gates</AUTHOR>
        <TITLE>Designing A Data Warehouse </TITLE>
        <NAME>Developer Times</NAME>
        <YEAR>2010</YEAR>
        <BEGIN>122</BEGIN>
        <END>125</END>
        <VOLUME>8</VOLUME>
        <VOLNUMBER>5</VOLNUMBER>
    </PUBLICATION>
    <PUBLICATION>
        <AUTHOR>Bradley Woods</AUTHOR>
        <AUTHOR>Tony Soprano </AUTHOR>
        <TITLE>Pragmatic Software Development</TITLE>
        <NAME>Developer Times </NAME>
        <YEAR>2011</YEAR>
        <BEGIN>35</BEGIN>
        <END>45</END>
        <VOLUME>14</VOLUME>
        <VOLNUMBER>9</VOLNUMBER>
    </PUBLICATION>
    <PUBLICATION>
        <AUTHOR>Bradley Woods</AUTHOR>
        <TITLE>Starting A Career in Software Development</TITLE>
        <NAME>Developer Times </NAME>
        <YEAR>2012</YEAR>
        <BEGIN>145</BEGIN>
        <END>148</END>
        <VOLUME>35</VOLUME>
        <VOLNUMBER>10</VOLNUMBER>
    </PUBLICATION>
    <PUBLICATION>
        <AUTHOR>Bradley Woods</AUTHOR>
        <TITLE>Using Sql Server 2012</TITLE>
        <NAME>BI Developer Weekly </NAME>
        <YEAR>2013</YEAR>
        <BEGIN>15</BEGIN>
        <END>50</END>
        <VOLUME>1</VOLUME>
        <VOLNUMBER>11</VOLNUMBER>
    </PUBLICATION>
    <PROJECT>
        <TITLE>Directory Data Warehouse</TITLE>
        <NAME>Insurance</NAME>
        <AMOUNT>$100,000</AMOUNT>
        <BEGIN>2012</BEGIN>
        <END>Present</END>
        <ROLE>Architect</ROLE>
    </PROJECT>
    <PROJECT>
        <TITLE>BI Report Server</TITLE>
        <NAME>Insurance</NAME>
        <AMOUNT>$50,000</AMOUNT>
        <BEGIN>2011</BEGIN>
        <END>2012</END>
        <ROLE>Assistant Architect</ROLE>
    </PROJECT>
    <PROJECT>
        <TITLE>CodeIgniter Website</TITLE>
        <NAME>MentorMe.Com</NAME>
        <AMOUNT>$10,000</AMOUNT>
        <BEGIN>2010</BEGIN>
        <END>2011</END>
        <ROLE>Lead Developer</ROLE>
    </PROJECT>
    <PROJECT>
        <TITLE>Wordpress Website</TITLE>
        <NAME>ShavingCulture.com</NAME>
        <AMOUNT>$3,000</AMOUNT>
        <BEGIN>2009</BEGIN>
        <END>2010</END>
        <ROLE>Developer</ROLE>
    </PROJECT>

</VITAE>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("container").write('<table>');` , why are you doing that?

Comment: looking for div element to place the table i am going to create

Comment: it should be `nodeValue` not `NodeValue`

Comment: Run it in Chrome or a browser with Firebug and inspect how the generated HTML looks like after your script has run.

Comment: @mzedeler when I run it no additional rows are appended. I have also attempted doing windows.alert("number of degrees" + edu.length; When I run this the alert doesnt show up with the length but it does as regular text.

Comment: Okay. Then you have to fire up a JavaScript debugger (i recommend the one built into Chrome) and step through your code to figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
'/<h4></td>';  => '</h4></td>'
```

And if you are tired of writing:

```
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML+=
```

...you might consider writing:

```
var html = "";

html += ....
html += ....

document.getElementById("container").innerHTML+= html;
```

You have also written this:

```
var xmlDoc

function getEducation() 
{
    ...
    var xmlObj = xmlDoc.documentElement;
```

1) The first line is an error because it doesn't end in a semi-colon.
2) xmlDoc is undefined, and undefined does not have a property named documentElement.

Comment: Did you change NodeValue to nodeValue as well?

Comment: Another thing you can do is alert() or console.log() the values you are retrieving from your xml file on the line before you add them to your html to see if you have the correct values.

Comment: I mentioned this in the post comments just a minute ago. I have not tried console.log() though and will see if that helps me find the issue.

Comment: Thanks for that, huge error. Dont know how I did not see that blunder. Unfortunately it still does not work.

Comment: You should be using some type of plugin for your browser that shows any javascript errors.  What browser do you like?

Answer (score 1):

1. xmlDoc is not defined somewhere
2. you open the  XMLHttpRequest, but you **did not send it**

Comment: how do you send it? I have the request, open it with a get, and get the responseXML.

Comment: call `xmlhttp.send(null);` after `xmlhttp.open("GET", "cv.xml", false);`

Comment: I've  tried it(of course I've also fixed the other mentioned bugs  ) , and it works.

Comment: What happens when you console.log(vitae)?

Comment: please inform yourself how to use the console